# Removing test IAP

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

When I download the app from the playstore and then buy something from the shop, [I only get to see a test shop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlGPO.jpg). My goal is to have a shop in which if you want to buy something you need to pay real money. So that it isn't in a test environment anymore. Does anyone know how why the shop type is in test mode, although I've tested it in release mode?

What I've tried:

1. Adding my credit card information to google play.
2. Testing it when the app was released
3. Turning on IAP

More Information:

1. The price ID coincide in Unity and Play Console
2. The price is correct
3. I use CodelessIAP/IAP Button

Comment: can someone please be more specific what exactly is missing? This question has been closed 2 times after I edited it and I don't know what exactly is wrong with it. Furthermore, the person which wrote the answer seemed to have understood it but it is still marked that it needs clarification. I'm really frustrated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you set up your testing environment? Did you follow the step in Google's doc? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

> To test during the development phase, we recommend leveraging license testers to run through the scenarios described in this topic. To configure license testers, see Test in-app billing with application licensing.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777

> Set up application licensing To set up application licensing, start by
> adding your list of tester's Gmail addresses in Play Console.
>
> Open Play Console. Click Setup > License testing. In "Add license
> testers" box, enter your testers' Gmail addresses. In the bottom right
> corner of the screen, select Save changes.

To see the real purchase process, remove your account from the license testers list

Or alternately, log your current account out of your test device and create a new Google account.

Comment: I don't have any license testers set. But I am an internal tester might this be an issue?

Comment: I'm unsure whether the reason was that I was registered as the owner or that I was registered as an internal tester. But removed those Email-addresses from my google play account and now I see the real purchase process. It didn't work when I only changed the email-address on google play